# Using $timeout to limit the amount of http request that go out in Angularjs 1.2 Search app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-typeahead

I'm doing a type ahead style form that has a ng-model of **findSearchValue** and when the user types in the input I watch this and when it updates I fire off the search function.  The issue that I'm having is when a user types a word (for example *Spaceship*) the function fires off 9 requests for *Spaceship*; 1 for each letter in the word.

I tried using a timeout, but all this does is wait 900ms and then fires off all 9 requests. What would ensure that the request is only fired after the user has stopped typing for a given amount of time.

Here is my current code:

```
$scope.findSearchValue = '';

$scope.getFindResults = function(findSearchValue) {
  if ($scope.findSearchValue.length > 2) {
    $timeout(function(){
      $http.get('/search.json?term=' + $scope.findSearchValue).success(function(data) {
        $scope.findResults = data;
        $scope.showSearchResults = true;
      });
    }, 900);
  } else {
    $scope.showSearchResults = false;
  }
};

$scope.$watch('findSearchValue',  function(newValue, oldValue) {
  if (newValue !== oldValue) {
    $scope.getFindResults();
  }
});
```

Also, I know there are plenty of directives that handle this use case.  I do not feel like installing a large directive just to do something so small.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want to [debounce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions). You should drop the extra `$timeout` code and just do:

```
ng-model-options="{ debounce: 900 }"
```

on the element.

**EDIT**: As mentioned below in the comments the above requires Angularjs 1.3. If you need to debounce but cannot upgrade your angularjs install then try something like this: [github.com/shahata/angular-debounce](http://github.com/shahata/angular-debounce)

Comment: Sadly the same issue happens.  It makes a call for each letter I type instead of waiting and only making one call for the full word.

Comment: And now I know why.  Debounce is only for Angularjs 1.3 so I'll need to figure out another solution.

Comment: @Mr.BigglesWorth For angular projects where upgrading wasn't an option I just loaded another directive like: https://github.com/shahata/angular-debounce

Comment: Great answer Jack and this worked perfectly with the directive.  I'd append that to your original answer.  I'll accept this as the answer.

Comment: @Mr.BigglesWorth Thanks! I've appended the note about debounce pre-1.3 to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Store the old timeout promise and cancel it every time a new change comes.
The key is to use `$timeout.cancel(promise)`. `promise` is returned by `$timeout()`. 
Using your code (untested):

```
$scope.findSearchValue = '';

var promise = null;
$scope.getFindResults = function(findSearchValue) {
  if ($scope.findSearchValue.length > 2) {
    if (promise) {
      $timeout.cancel(promise);
    }
    promise = $timeout(function(){
      $http.get('/search.json?term=' + $scope.findSearchValue).success(function(data) {
        $scope.findResults = data;
        $scope.showSearchResults = true;
      });
    }, 900);
  } else {
    $scope.showSearchResults = false;
  }
};

$scope.$watch('findSearchValue',  function(newValue, oldValue) {
  if (newValue !== oldValue) {
    $scope.getFindResults();
  }
});
```

Comment: This answer works as well and is totally viable if you don't want to use a directive.